# get response header of request from HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, header, response, webmethod

i am trying to implement my code as per these requirement. That is saying `The response to this POST will include a header named LOCATION, which is a URL with parameters indicating where to upload the file via a second POST.`. For request i have did below code but i stuck at point where i need to get LOCATION from header. For request i did below code and i want to get LOCATION from Header of response.

```
            string responseStr = "";
            HttpStatusCode statusCode;
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(URL);
            //request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(bigApiUserID, BigApiKey);
            request.Method = "POST";
            byte[] bytes;
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringOrder);
            request.Headers.Add("Authentication", token);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse response;
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            statusCode = response.StatusCode;
            response.Headers 
            if (Convert.ToString(response.StatusCode) == "OK")
            {
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
                return responseStr;
            }
```

Comment: WebHeaderCollection collection = response.Headers;
            string location = collection["location"];

Comment: Where i will place this code

Comment: Instead of :  response.Headers